# How to I calculate the total duration when a threshold is crossed?

Tags: algorithm, matlab, logic

I am using MATLAB to develop a code that should let me know the total duration when a sensor reading crosses the threshold value.

```
if SensorReadingsFunction(nTracks) > 5
        % Fusion lost, log the time stamp
        if isempty(lostLog) || lostLog(end) ~= nTracks
            lostLog = [lostLog, nTracks];
            
            lostTimestamp = scene.SimulationTime; 

            fuseLostTimestamp = [fuseLostTimestamp; lostTimestamp];

            % fusedRegainedTimestamp= [];
        end
        status = 'Sensor Lost';        
    else
        
        % Fusion regained, log the time stamp
    if ~isempty(lostLog) && lostLog(end) ~= nTracks-1
        regainedLog = [regainedLog, nTracks-1];
        regainedTimestamp = scene.SimulationTime;
        fusedRegainedTimestamp = [fusedRegainedTimestamp; regainedTimestamp];
        % Calculate the duration of lost fusion if fusion was regained
        if ~isempty(fuseLostTimestamp) && ~isempty(fusedRegainedTimestamp)
            lostDuration = fusedRegainedTimestamp(1) - fuseLostTimestamp(1);
        end
        lostDurationRecord = [lostDurationRecord; lostDuration];
        % Reset lost timestamp when fusion is regained for the first time
        %fuseLostTimestamp = [];
    end
    status = 'Sensor Gained';
    end
```

This block of code is able to check if a function that outputs sensorreading at a timestep is more than the threshold (5) then sensor is lost otherwise it is gained.

Currently, I am getting the time sensor was lost and the time sensor was regained. However, I am having a hard time on calculating the duration the sensor was lost.

What I want to do is: if at timesteps 2,3, 4,5, the sensor was list, the total duration should be 3 min. This is all taking place in a simulation. So time is according to the simulation.

Here is what my fuseLostTimestamp looks like:

```
0
69
70
71
72
90
93
96
97
98
```

What this data means is from from timestep 69 to 70, the sensor was lost. Then from 73 to 89 the sensor was regained. Later at 90, fuseLostTimestamp.

My fusedRegainedTimestamp looks like:

```
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
20
21
22
23
24
25
26
27
28
29
30
31
32
33
34
35
36
37
38
39
40
41
42
43
44
45
46
47
48
49
50
51
52
53
54
55
56
57
58
59
60
61
62
63
64
65
66
67
68
74
75
76
77
78
79
80
81
82
83
84
85
86
87
88
89
92
95
100
```

What this data means is that from 2 to 68 the sensor was working fine (regained) then again referring to fusedLosttimestep the sensor was lost till 72, then at 74 to 89 the sensor was regained. This logic continues through the array.

How do I calculate the time duration of each time the sensor was lost?
Is there any better way?

Comment: The easiest way is to maintain a counter that, in the same loop that creates `fuseLostTimestamp`, increments for each timestep that the signal is absent. Then output the counter and reset when the signal is regained.

Comment: Thank you that is exactly what I was trying to do by the line ```  % fusedLostTimestamp= [] ```. By using this line, I thought it would reset the array by emptying it or by reinitializing the array. But I don't know what mistake am I making.  Ignore ```  % fusedRegainedTimestamp= [];``` comment.

Comment: What exactly do you want your output to look like? For the durations above, do you just want array that looks like `[3;2]`? What are `lostLog` and `regainedLog`? They seem to be redundant. Is it possible to accumulate all of the sensor readings first and then post-process the data? If so, then @Stewie suggested a potentially more concise approach.

Comment: The outcome I want is an array of all the durations for which the readings were lost. output = [2; 10; 3; 50; 10...  and so on] You are right lostLog and regainedLog are redundant. Please ignore. Yes @Stewie has given me an almost accurate answer. I have commented the problem with the answer below. I hope I have clarified now.

Comment: I don't understand how your `output = [2; 10; 3; 50; 10...]` relates to the example above where the sensor is lost at timesteps 69-72, 90, 93, and 96-98.

Comment: The output array was just with arbitrary numbers but okay here is how it'd look. output = [2; 74-69; 92 - 90; 95 - 93; 100-96]; What this means is for 1st element-> lost at 0, regained at 2. 2nd element->lost at 69, regained at 74...and so on. The difference is the duration.